# How to detect Push Upgrade

Tags: appexchange, push-upgrade

Is there a way to detect Push Upgrades, or Patch via Apex for Managed Packages?

Whenever a Upgrade happens, I need to notify the Admin Users to recompile all the Classes for better performance via a VF page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class that implements the `InstallHandler` and set-up your package to use this as the post install class.

When the `onInstall()` method is called, it is passed a `InstallContext` object, that contains `isUpgrade()` and `isPush()` methods.

See documentation and examples here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm

Comment: I tried with a simple snippet as follows...but did not work
`global class PostInstallClass implements InstallHandler {
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        UpgradeOrInstall__c uoc = UpgradeOrInstall__c.getValues('IsUpgraded');
        uoc.IsUpgraded__c = 'TRUE';
        update uoc;
    }
}`

Comment: The custom setting update works fine in Dev Console. I tried this for a fresh installation as of now.

Comment: OK! Got  the issue. Have to specify the Post-Install Script Class in the Package. Thanks :)